# Regular Expression in Actionscript 3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I need a AS3 regular expression that allows me to find/replace in strings like these:

```
var str1:String = "<value1 att="1"> some text</value1>";
var str2:String = "<value1 att="1" var="a">  some text and more</value1>";
var str3:String = "<value1 att="ok" var="b" def="12">     some text</value1>";
```

to this:

```
str1 = "<value1 att="1">*some text</value1>";
str2 = "<value1 att="1" var="a">**some text and more</value1>";
str3 = "<value1 att="ok" var="b" def="12">*****some text</value1>";
```

I want to be able to replace the spaces at the beginning (inside the > <) for other character. It shouldn't affect the number of character at the right of the spaces or the attributes in the value1 definition.

Comment: You do know that if you put that text in a CDATA block, you won't need to the replacing? ActionScript will then not cut off the whitespace.

Comment: yeap, thanks for the comment. it's a different situation.

Comment: don't forget to escape your string quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there are no "* " sequences in the text blocks, this should work:

```
var s:String = "<value1 att='ok' var='b' def='12'>     some text</value1>";

//find all spaces after a tag closing bracket and replace with a *
s = s.replace(/>\s/g, ">*");

//find all spaces after a * and replace it with a *
//keep doing this until no more can be found
while (s.match(/>\*+\s/g).length) {
    s = s.replace(/\*\s/g, "**");
}
```

I can't think of a way to do it in one `replace` though.

Comment: tks, for the answer. Problem is if you have other tags that you dont want to touch, like <value2> <value3> <valueN>, that may not work.

Comment: how about something like this: />\s*.*?<\/value1>/gi

Comment: but how can I replace only the sapces?

Comment: Aha. But you did not put that in your requirements ;) If they're all separate strings as described in your question you could easily test them before you do the replacing.

Comment: i.e. only replace `if (XML(s).name() == "value1")` for instance

Comment: If you could find a way of finding out the length of the returned substring, then doing it in one replace should be possible. i've been trying different stuff at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ (great tool for testing regexs) but RIAstar's answer is pretty much what I came up with

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to accomplish what you need is to use a function in replace() expression.

```
var replaceMethod:Function = function (match:String, tagName:String, tagContent:String, spaces:String, targetText:String, index:int, whole:String) : String
{
    trace("\t", "found", spaces.length,"spaces in tag '"+tagName+"'");
    trace("\t", "matched string:", match);
    // check tag name or whatever you may want
    // do something with found spaces
    var replacement:String = spaces.replace(" ", "*");    
    return "<"+tagName+" "+tagContent+">"+replacement+targetText;
}

var str1:String = '<value1 att="1">    some text</value1>';
var exp:RegExp = /<(\w+)([ >].*?)>(\s+)(some text)/gm;

trace("before:", str1);
str1 = str1.replace(exp, replaceMethod);
trace("after:", str1);
```

It's not performance-safe though; if you are using huge blocks of text and/or launching this routine very frequently, you may want to do something more comlicated, but optimized. One optimization technique is reducing the number of arguments of replaceMathod().

p.s. I think this can be done with one replace() expression and without using replaceMethod(). Look at positive lookaheads and noncapturing groups, may be you can figure it out. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=12_Using_Regular_Expressions_09.html