# Using a regular expression to insert text in a match

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

Regular Expressions are incredible. I'm in my regex infancy so help solving the following would be greatly appreciated.

I have to search through a string to match for a P character that's not surrounded by operators, power or negative signs. I then have to insert a multiplication sign. Case examples are:

```
33+16*55P would become 33+16*55*P
2P would become 2*P
P( 33*sin(45) ) would become P*(33*sin(45))
```

I have written some regex that I think handles this although I don't know how using regex I can insert a character:

The reg is I've written is:

```
[^\^\+\-\/\*]?P+[^\^\+\-\/\*]
```

The language where the RegEx will be used is ActionScript 3.

A live example of the regex can be seen at:

http://www.regexr.com/39pkv

I would be massively grateful if someone could show me how I insert a multiplication sign in middle of the match ie P2, becomes P*2, 22.5P becomes 22.5P

ActionScript 3 has search, match and replace functions that all utilise regular expressions. I'm unsure how I'd use string.replace( expression, replaceText ) in this context.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonder (and inevitable frustration that will lead to tearing your hair out) that is regular expressions. You should probably read over the documentation on [using regular expressions in ActionScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html), as well as [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471356/regular-expression-in-actionscript-3).

You'll need to combine `RegExp.test()` with the `String.replace()` function. I don't know ActionScript, so I don't know if it will work as is, but based on the documentation linked above, the below should be a good start for testing and getting an idea of what the form of your solution might look like. I think @Vall3y is right. To get the replace right, you'd want to first check for anything leading up to a P, then for anything after a P. So two functions is probably easier to get right without getting too fancy with the Regex:

```
   private function multiplyBeforeP(str:String):String {
      var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("([^\^\+\-\/\*]?)P", "i");
      return str.replace(pattern, "$1*P");
  }

   private function multiplyAfterP(str:String):String {
      var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("P([^\^\+\-\/\*])", "i");
      return str.replace(pattern, "P*$1");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex is used to find patterns in strings. It cannot be used to manipulate them. You will need to use action script for that.

Many programming languages have a string.replace method that accepts a regex pattern. Since you have two cases (inserting after and before the P), a simple solution would be to split your regex into two (`[^\^\+\-\/\*]?P+` and `P+[^\^\+\-\/\*]` for example, this might need adjustment), and switch each pattern with the matching string ("*P" and "P*")